# Unable to populate secondary table from concatenated info from primary table in SQL Plus

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have an assignment that I am trying to correct for a future assignment:
For the Vehicle_Code primary key column use an Oracle sequence to populate the values. For the Description column use all concatenated combinations of Make and Model of vehicles you have. Use a PL/SQL block to populate the Description column by SELECTing the combinations from your OLTP_VEHICLES table and then INSERTing the combinations into your new VEHICLES table, which would best be performed via a cursor in a loop.
Now, I did this before but against the wrong table.  I was supposed to create a new table to insert that information into.  I have created the new table and made what I thought would be appropriate corrections, but my new tables always return 0 lines. Below is my original code and updated code.  Can someone please tell me what I am missing?  Thanks!

ORIGINAL CODE:

```
DROP SEQUENCE OLTP_Counter;
CREATE SEQUENCE OLTP_Counter START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
MINVALUE 1;

DECLARE
CURSOR OLTP_COUNT IS SELECT vehicle_code,make, model FROM OLTP_VEHICLES;
vc varchar2(30);
model VARCHAR2(30);
make VARCHAR2(30);
BEGIN
OPEN OLTP_COUNT;
LOOP
FETCH OLTP_COUNT INTO vc, make, model;
EXIT WHEN  OLTP_COUNT % NOTFOUND;
UPDATE OLTP_VEHICLES SET description=make||' '||model where vehicle_code=vc;
END LOOP;
CLOSE OLTP_COUNT;
COMMIT;
END;
/
SELECT * FROM OLTP_VEHICLES ORDER BY vehicle_code;
```

NEW (BROKEN) CODE:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE vehicle_counter START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
MINVALUE 1;

DECLARE
CURSOR vehicle_count IS SELECT vehicle_code,make, model FROM OLTP_VEHICLES;
vc VARCHAR2(30);
model VARCHAR2(30);
make VARCHAR2(30);
BEGIN
OPEN vehicle_count;
LOOP
FETCH vehicle_count INTO vc, make, model;
EXIT WHEN  vehicle_count % NOTFOUND;
UPDATE vehicles SET description=make||' '||model where Vehicle_Code=vc;
END LOOP;
CLOSE vehicle_count;
COMMIT;
END;
/

SELECT * FROM vehicles ORDER BY Vehicle_Code;
```

This new code doesn't actually populate the vehicles table.  It returns 'no rows selected'

ADDED INFO

Below I have my tables for OLTP_Vehicles and for vehicles.  My variable lengths should be sufficient.

```
CREATE TABLE OLTP_VEHICLES (
    Vehicle_Code VARCHAR2(10),
    CONSTRAINT OLTPV_pk PRIMARY KEY(Vehicle_Code),
    vin VARCHAR2(17),
    type VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    model VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    make VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    trade_id VARCHAR2 (10)NOT NULL, 
    wholesale_cost NUMERIC(10,2) NOT NULL,
    where_from VARCHAR2(30)NOT NULL,
    sale_id VARCHAR2(10),
    dealer_id VARCHAR2(10)
    );

CREATE TABLE vehicles (
    Vehicle_Code VARCHAR2(10),
    CONSTRAINT vehicles_pk PRIMARY KEY(Vehicle_Code),
    description VARCHAR2(65)
    );
```

Comment: 1. In oltp_vehicles table, all columns have length less than or equal to 30 ?                    2. How much length has description column of vehicles table ?

Comment: Quote from your question: _SELECTing the combinations from your OLTP_VEHICLES table and then INSERTing the combinations into your new VEHICLES table_. I don't see any `INSERT` in the new (broken) code you posted. Also, I couldn't find the structure of your new VEHICLES table. Did I miss something?

Comment: @Barbaros Özhan I checked my datalengths and they should be good. I will add my code to the post so you can see.  I also updated my variable names but that didn't seem to help.

Comment: Did you get any error message by using `sqlerrm` ? Indeed,  `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON` should be applied. Btw, your lengths seem OK. So, my answer fails :)

Comment: In the original block you wrote, you're updating `description` column of `oltp_vehicles`, but it has no such column ... And are you sure `vehicle_code` columns' values are common for both tables ?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I think my issue might be getting my sequence count into the vc variable.  I don't think I am doing that.  I think I have set up the sequence, but then I don't think I am referencing it again.  I don't think I noticed this error before because I referenced the OLTP table that already had vehicle_code data.  Does that make sense?  If I am on the right path, any idea how to plug that sequence data into my new variable?

Comment: @Barbaros Özhan There is no description column in the OTLP table.  As part of the assignment, I am supposed to create a vehicles table with a two columns, vehicle_code (PK) and description.  The vehicle_code is supposed to populate with that sequence and the description is supposed to be a combination of OLTP_Vehicles.make and OLTP_Vehicles.model.

Comment: but in both tables, vehicle_code columns are primary, I mean you're required to insert.

Comment: Previously, I didn't actually create the vehicles table, just added a new description column to OLTP_vehicles.

Comment: as for the 'Insert' I thought that is what the FETCH, UPDATE, AND SET commands were doing.

Comment: @sirpigpin No, you insert rows with [`INSERT`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/INSERT.html). You might also look at [`MERGE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/MERGE.html), and [Cursor FOR loops](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/cursor-FOR-LOOP-statement.html).

Comment: @WilliamRobertson I am a little confused on this then.  I didn't have an INSERT statement before and I was able to build my Description column.  Why did it work then and not now?  Is it because I created that column inside the same table that the other data was pulled from or something?

Comment: In your "broken" code, you're updating the VEHICLES table, which apparently doesn't have any rows in it. Did you mean to use `INSERT` instead of `UPDATE`?

Comment: @BobJarvis I am not sure.  I am a super noob at sql... How would I change it to be an insert?  Just change 'Update' to Insert?

Comment: I strongly suggest you spend some time learning SQL. There are many free online resources to help you with this - for example [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7S_tz1z_5bA), or [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Pzj7Aj25lw), or [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HXV3zeQKqGY). Best of luck.

Comment: @BobJarvis I totally agree.  That is what I am trying to do now.  Any way, I figured it out.  Before I was able to run my code without the insert because I was updating records that already existed.  Since I was creating a new table I had to add (or INSERT) the new records.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!  Before I was UPDATING records that already existed.  The new table needed an INSERT instead.  Thanks for all those who gave me suggestions.  As someone who is still learning, none of this stuff comes naturally.  I need all of the help I can get!

```
DECLARE
CURSOR vehicle_counter IS SELECT Vehicle_Code, make, model FROM OLTP_VEHICLES;
vc VARCHAR2(10);
model OLTP_Vehicles.model%type;
make OLTP_Vehicles.make%type;
BEGIN
OPEN vehicle_counter;
LOOP
FETCH vehicle_counter INTO vc,make, model;
dbms_output.put_line(make);
EXIT WHEN  vehicle_counter % NOTFOUND;
INSERT INTO vehicles values(vc,make||' '||model);
END LOOP;
CLOSE vehicle_counter;
COMMIT;
EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
END;
/
```